# Magento 2 - How can I add custom template file into <head> in backend/admin?

Tags: magento-2.0.7

I know that we can add a custom block in the head as follows :

```
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
<body>
    <referenceContainer name="head.additional">
        <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" name="block_name" template="path_to_file.phtml" />
    </referenceContainer>
</body>
```

but when i tried the same in admin i am unable to add the block, have tried following reference blocks till now :

```
<referenceContainer name="head">

<referenceContainer name="head.additional">
```

When i try adding block using

```
<referenceContainer name="content">
```

it works great but as i need to add dynamic name of the Google fonts i need it in `<head>` tag.

I am trying to add above code in backend's sales_order_view.xml

Any help will be great.

Comment: Have you find any solution for this?

Comment: Not at the time i needed, i managed to find a work around though.

Answer (score 1):

You have to try with below code,

Replace

```
<referenceContainer name="head.additional">
```

With

```
<referenceBlock name="head.additional">
```

**You have to use referenceBlock tag.**

Comment: Have you solved your issue?